# Using opscode's omnibus installer in windows 7

Tags: python, ruby, chef-infra, vagrant

I am working my way through a video tutorial at http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/

I am working on win7 and using git-bash for my terminal. I have installed the latest virtualbox - 4.2.12 and the latest vagrant - 1.22.

I tried to run vagrant up and got: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
          /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
  creating Makefile      

  make
  sh: 1: make: not found
```

Once of the answers given by jtimberman is:

```
The basebox you're using does not have the "build-essential" package installed by default, and it has a "[shell provisioner][1]" that installs the Chef gem into the default Ruby environment. Chef has a dependency on the JSON RubyGem, which itself has C extensions that must be compiled. This is what is looking for `make`.    
To resolve this issue, I'd recommend using Opscode's "omnibus" [full stack installer for Chef][2]. This can be used by changing the shell provisioner line to:    
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "curl -L https://opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash"    
The `[install.sh][3]` script simply inspects the VM to determine what its platform is so it can retrieve the proper URL from an S3 bucket. If you prefer you can use the constructed URL to download the .deb file directly:

https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/11.04/x86_64/chef_11.4.4-2.ubuntu.11.04_amd64.deb

And then install it:

dpkg -i chef_11.4.4-2.ubuntu.11.04_amd64.deb
```

I have not been able to get the first method to work and would like to try the second. would:

```
 dpkg -i chef_11.4.4-2.ubuntu.11.04_amd64.deb
```

work on win7. If not how do I get this working in windows?

Comment: No, this command is for Debian Linux. You have a problem that is only related to Vagrant and Ruby, how did you install Ruby for Windows? It seems to lack the functionality to compile native extensions, maybe use http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile native extensions in Windows, you must install the [Ruby DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/). Joshua's answer is valid for Debian-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to sethvargo.
In addition to the Ruby DevKit, you also need the client library for your native software. 
For example, in order to compile/install ruby-oci8 gem, you should have the Oracle Client installed on your computer as well.